# Spark prepending local directory to absolute path

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I've gotten simple spark jobs (spark 1.6, scala 2.10) deployed in cluster mode that read and write to the local filesystem running on a linux cluster, but am facing path issues when doing the same trying to launch jobs to a cluster running Windows Server 2012.

I've tried all sorts of path combinations (e.g. file://C:/Users/file.txt, file://C://Users//file.txt, file:///C:/Users/file.txt, file:\C:\Users\file.txt) without success.  One of the errors seems to be Spark prepending the local path on the remote machine to the absolute path I'm intending the cluster to use.

I.e. the spark jar on the worker node is at C:\Users\file.jar, but the error on the spark cluster driver is "java.io.FileNotFoundException:  C:\Users\remote_home\file:\C:\Users\Administrator"

Comment: I don't think it is possible to prepend anything to an absolute path. Do you mean look in directory abc then look in directory 'absolute path'?

Comment: No, I mean that the jar file for each worker node in the spark cluster is at the location C:\abc\file.jar, but the directory spark looks for is C:\Users\remote_home\file:\C:\abc\file.jar

Comment: mklink /D C:\temp11111   \\server\share\foldername\ will maybe work, see http://superuser.com/questions/210824/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using only forward slashes ("/") in the path, e.g. (file:///C:/Users/file.txt)

Answer (score 2):

One workaround in accessing local windows dir path: you can put your .txt file in any of the eclipse /src/../.. folders (say src/test/resources) and then replace path in program as:

```
JavaRDD<String> data1 = sc.textFile("C:/Users/XXX/XXX/src/test/resources/Text.txt");
```